# CSS sizing Error of hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a grid of thumbnails and a hidden overlay div for each thumbnail.

This hidden overlay becomes visible after clicking on "share" in each thumbnail.

The problem I'm encountering is that upon becoming visible, this hidden overlay takes up the full window space, instead of just taking up the size of the thumbnail.

The overlay for each thumbnail should be the same size as the grid thumbnail (orange box)  and not the entire window.

I've added the [code example here](http://goo.gl/l7u9Id). Any help  tips would be useful!

Thanks!

Comment: Make card height as some fixed value like #card {height: 400px;} and Your .share_sheet {
  position: relative;
  top:-300px;
  left:0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your '.share_sheet' is position absolute. Absolute makes it 0,0 to the next relative position which is the screen.

If you set the '#card' to position relative that should fix it.